# Joomla articles Link issue in editor

Tags: joomla3.0

When adding a article link on the editor, article shows with homepage menus and image slider

How to remove it ?

Example:

[I want this way when clicking on the link.](http://i65.tinypic.com/30lm0yo.jpg)

[But it comes on this way](http://vishwa.nsf.ac.lk/nsf/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8&catid=11&Itemid=101)

Thanks

Comment: I think you have the same link twice? It might be a good to post a screenshot of the current and desired appearance so it is easy to see the difference.

Comment: I want it this way http://i65.tinypic.com/30lm0yo.jpg not like this way http://vishwa.nsf.ac.lk/nsf/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8&catid=11&Itemid=101

Answer (score 0):

You should have two menus:

1. Main menu (default)
2. Main menu (in your own language)

And for each category, add a menu item (type: category list) into main menu (default).

In the module manager, use the menu 2 (own language), not the menu 1 (default).

I have encountered same trouble a few years ago. After a deep and long research I can say that the unique solution is as I mentioned.

For better answer I need to know your category tree and menu structure.